# Free automatic organic synthesis Linux command line program

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, computational-chemistry, software

I'm trying to find a free automatic organic synthesis Linux command line program which take mol or smile files as input. I have random molecules and I'd like to know how difficult above a baseline they will be to synthesize. An implementation of synthetic accessibility and not a full step wise synthesis program would also be acceptable. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would be very surprised if such a program exists for anything but a small subset of similarly structured molecules.  Additionally, refer to the [help section](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) with respect to questions that are purely of a simulation nature.

Comment: A general solution to this problem, by the way, would be literally worth zillions of dollars.

Comment: And probably a Nobel Prize (with its additional 8 million Swedish Kronor).

Comment: @bobthechemist awh well then you can successfully be surprised as I found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The SAscore is now implemented in RDkit and available for [download](http://www.mail-archive.com/rdkit-discuss@lists.sourceforge.net/msg03477.html).

Comment: If you're wondering what "SAscore" is, see the following open-access article: "Estimation of synthetic accessibility score of drug-like molecules based on molecular complexity and fragment contributions" http://www.jcheminf.com/content/1/1/8